# Quadratic residue and cubic polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, cubics, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

The question is simple: Can
$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} (\frac{ax^3 +bx^2 +cx +d}{p} )$
be expressed as a closed form ? 
(It's a Legendre Symbol)

Comment: Are you counting points on elliptic curves?

Comment: Uh....I don't think I completely understood your question, but to elaborate, I'm counting the number of quadratic residues

Comment: This is one the types of exponential sums / character sums that can be written in terms of stuff straddling number theory and algebraic geometry. Anyway, it is known that the sum has absolute value at most $2\sqrt{p}$, and that's about it.

Comment: How can that be proved? Do you have any links?

Comment: @Junsukim This is known as Hasse's Theorem. [Here's one reference](http://koclab.cs.ucsb.edu/teaching/ecc/eccPapers/Washington-ch04.pdf) (Washington, Theorem 4.2), but it is phrased using elliptic curves.